# wordpress redirection loop in woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

Hi I am having a problem with my wordpress site after I changed my theme and redesigned the website and also deleting and reinstalling woocommerce ( I did not update because updating coused wp-admin to become blank-white and reinstalling made it all fine exept this following problem.)

all links to products in the shop page are to "/product(in hebrew)/product-name/"
and when i access the products in wp-admin and hit the "view product" page it goes to "/products(english)/product-name/"

the problem is when I click on a product from the shop front-end I get a redirection loop error. i need to fix this ASAP.

no sure how to fix this problem.

website: www.tikanti.co.il/חנות/

Answer (score 1):

i found out a way to fix it...

just went to
setting > parmalinks > changed one of the options for woocommerce and it refreshed the whole thing to whatever I chose.

no more loop thank god!!!!!

Comment: this is a bug due to translation feature of Woocomerce

Answer (score 1):

to solve this you need to log into your **cpanel** and change the **.htaccess** permissions to **777** or **755**
then go to **wp-admin** page then **setting > parmalinks >** 
then change **Common Settings** to **post name**
this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can set redirect according to user role.

```
 //Redirect users to custom URL based on their role after login

function wp_woo_custom_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {

// Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
$role = $user->roles[0];
$dashboard = admin_url();
$myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'my-account' ) );

if( $role == 'administrator' ) {

    //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
    $admin_redirect = get_option('admin_redirect');
    $redirect = $admin_redirect;
} elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {

    //Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
    $shop_manager_redirect = get_option('shop_manager_redirect');
    $redirect = $shop_manager_redirect;
} elseif ( $role == 'customer' || $role == 'subscriber' ) {

    //Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
    $customer_redirect = get_option('customer_redirect');
    $redirect = $customer_redirect;
} else {

    //Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
    $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
}
return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wp_woo_custom_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Given above the code for that redirection and I have developed a [WooCommerce Login or Register Redirect plugin](http://www.e2softsolution.com/change-woocommerce-login-register-redirect-url/) for entry level user or nor technical or no-programmer.